# What is the meaning of this code segment?

Tags: python, statistics, iterator

I am trying to implement a function in python which takes in input an iterable and loops through it to perform some operation. I was confused about how to handle different iterables (example: lists and dictionaries cannot be looped in the same general way), so I looked in the `statistics` library in python and found that they are handling this situation like this: -

```
def variance(data, xbar=None):
    if iter(data) is data:        #<-----1
        data = list(data)
    ...
```

then, they are handling `data` as list everywhere.

So, my question is : -

- What is the meaning of (1); and
- Is this the right method as it is everytime making a new list out of data. Can't they simply use the iterator to loop through the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iter(something)` returns an iterator object that returns the elements of `something`. If `something` is already an iterator, it simply returns it unchanged. So

```
if iter(data) is data:
```

is a way of telling whether `data` is an iterator object. If it is, it converts it to a list of all the elements.

It's doing this because the code after that needs a real list of the elements. There are things you can do with a list that you can't do with an iterator, such as access specific elements, insert/delete elements, and loop over it multiple times. Iterators can only be processed sequentially.

Comment: Ok, but when I write ```d = {0:1, 1:2, 3:4}```, the ```if iter(d) is d``` returns false. Is dictionary not iterable?

Comment: I think a dict is *iterable*, but is not an iteration itself.